# Browser address bar often forgets the link after I press Enter and does nothing

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, url, opera

I have this problem that is bothering me for quite some time and it happens on my desktop and laptops.
It happens quite often, at least one time to a few times per day.

I mainly use Chrome and Opera and both exhibit this behavior:

- open a New tab
- type URL in Address bar
- press Enter
- URL gets deleted from the Address bar and no page loads
- type again the URL, press Enter and the page loads fine

I've changed the DNS on the router and in the IPv4 Windows configuration, but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mistype the URL when it disappeared?

Comment: it happens on a daily basis. i'm sure that it's not my mistake.

Comment: If you're sure there was no typing error, and it's happening on two different browsers, it might be some setting of the router.

Comment: Same on desktop and Android, all chrome-based browsers have this issue. I noticed it only for search terms, not URLs.

Comment: @user11153 is there any bug opened about it?   I was suspecting possible MTU differences for NAT/PPPOE.

Comment: @learner no idea. And it happens for URLs too. Just open a new tab, start typing before even 'new tab content' finished loading, press ENTER - and sometimes everything typed or pasted is just gone.